# how to plot Figure instances from other scripts

Tags: matplotlib

Is it possible to save and load the plot with all its attributes? E.g. pickle the Figure instance and then opening it in another script and redrawing as it was in the original script.

Script1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
fig, ax = plt.figure()
pd.to_pickle(fig,'fig.pkl')
```

Script2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
fig = pd.read_pickle(fig,'fig.pkl')
# Now plot it so that it looks like in script1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pickle.dump` to save:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pickle.dump(fig, open('fig.pkl', 'wb'))
```

And `pickle.load` to recover:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
fig = pickle.load(open('fig.pkl', 'rb'))
plt.show()
```

---

### Re: comment about storing figs in a dict

This works on my end -- `dump` the dict of figure handles:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot([1, 0], [0, 1])

figs = {'fig1': fig1, 'fig2': fig2}
pickle.dump(figs, open('figs.pickle', 'wb'))
```

Then `load` the dict and access the desired dict key:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
figs = pickle.load(open('figs.pickle', 'rb'))  
figs['fig1'] # or figs['fig2']
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my prescribed problem.
Now say that I nest several figures into a dictionary. Is it possible to load the dictionary and then recover the embedded figures?

Comment: Hmm if I understand correctly, I edited an example of a figure handle dict.